# Curl For Loop Reading Only Last Element Of Array

Tags: php, curl

Below is the code I am using.

It reads links from a textarea, and then gets the source code and finally filters the meta tags. However it only displays the last element in the array.

So if for example I put 3 websites into the textarea, it will only read the last one, the others are just shown as blank.

Have spent hours trying this, please help.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_POST['url'])){
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $url = explode("\n",$url);
    print_r($url);
    for($counter = 0; $counter < count($url); $counter++){
        $html = file_get_contents_curl($url[$counter]); // PASSING LAST VALUE OF ARRAY
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++){
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
        print
        ('
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <legend><b>URL: </b>'.$url[$counter].'</legend>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Title:</b></td><td>'.$title.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Description:</b></td><td>'.$description.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Keywords:</b></td><td>'.$keywords.'</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset><br />
        ');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($url);`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => http://www.site1.com [1] => http://www.site2.com [2] => http://www.site3.com )

Comment: Simplified your loop - working for me based on your info -> http://codepad.org/jkZHnfAo

Comment: the loop is dynamic, i said site1 site2 site3 as an example, the array if fine, curl however is only executing the last element of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an annoying little bug to find - but here is the (ridiculously simple) solution:

Your URLs are getting white space added to them, for all but the last URL therefore you'll need to trim it, you can do the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
```

If available, you could have possibly just used `file_get_contents()` (still requires you trimming the URL).

The second problem is that if there is no `meta` data then the old variables are used (from the previous loop) so just before the end of your main loop, after your `print()` add the following:

```
unset($title,$description,$keywords);
```

Comment: Just can't believe this simple solution could be that much of a headache! Fantastic!